# How to finish() MainActivity from Activity3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-theme, activity-finish

I'm developing an application in which I have a `MainActivity`, on that I have a button which calls `Activity1`(the theme of this activity is set to dialog i.e. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog`), so I can't finish the `MainActivity`, otherwise `Activity1` will be on top of home screen.

On my `Activity1`, my other activity i.e. `Activity2` is called. This is also same as `Activity1` with dialog theme. Now from `Activity2` I have called `Activity3` which is normal activity without dialog theme.

Now, I want to finish my `MainActivity` from `Activity2`.

How can I achieve that?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer. If I understand correctly, it should work for you

Comment: I try to understand why you want to close MainActivity. Do you want to close the app when back press in activity 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start each activity like `startActivityForResult()` and check result of activity.
So, if you want to close first activity, you should set specific result of each activity and call `finish()`. In each activity, you check `result` in `onActivityResult()`, so if you see your specified result, you should close this activity (or set result if it not first activity too)

In first activity, I want to start second

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

In second activity, I want to start third

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

So, In third activity I want to start fourth and close each other

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity4.class);
startActivity(i);

setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

And in each activity (1, 2) I should check method `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain, how it can be achieved. That will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Why do you want to finish() MainActivity?

Comment: @HoanNguyen Yes. I want that only, but from Activity3 as I explained in my question.

Comment: @Anupam I have added more details to my answer

Comment: For just out of curiosity, is it alright to not have `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` at the end of overriding `onActivityResult`?

Answer (score 1):

do you want to close Activity2, Activity1, and then MainActivity ?

if so, you can use the startActivityForResult and onActivityResult for each of the activities, and check if the returned result is the one that requests to close the current activity and pass it further.

if not, such a thing can be done using a service that will be bound between the activities.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to finish `MainActivity` when `Activity 3` is started. If this is the case and it is ok to clear the other two `Activities` as well, you can us an `Intent flag`

```
Intent intent (Activity2.this, Acitivity3.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

If I understand you correctly this will accomplish what you want. `Activity 3` will be started while clearing all other `Activities` from the stack.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a working flow android system would expect to occur thats why you cant shut down the whole app with one command. What you can do is to use the startActivityForResult and check the source, the status and close the activities in cascade.

Heres an example:
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

You can create specific codes for each activity that start the next one.

Answer (score 0):

While starting an activity, send your activity to new one as an extra. For example:

in main:

```
  Intent in= new Intent("your action");
  in.putExtra("preAct",this);
  startActivity(in);
```

Then use your preAct to finish it.

in new activity:

```
 Activity prev = (Activity)this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("preAct");
```

then all you need

```
 prev.finish()
```

to finish it whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

Check [noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) attribute of activity.
If You set it to true, user won't be able to get back to this activity after he leaves it.